# Why can’t claims under s214 Housing Act 2004 be issued in the small claims track?

Tags: england-and-wales, civil-law, tenant, civil-procedure, small-claims-court

Accordingly myriad materials online including as authoritative as Shelter, [section 214](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/34/section/214?timeline=false) claims must be brought under the Part 8 procedure, even where the maximum possible award would fall well within the threshold for the small claims track. What is the purpose of the Part 8 claim procedure, and why must s214 claims use it?

Comment: https://www.landlordlawblog.co.uk/2012/11/13/what-is-the-correct-procedure-for-claims-under-s-of-the-housing-act/?doing_wp_cron=1673568328.1633560657501220703125

Answer (score 3):

- Why use Part 8?

Because the Civil Procedure Rules say so.

See [Practice Direction 56.2(2.1)](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part56/pd_part56#IDANMC2):

> ...the claimant in a **landlord and tenant claim must use the Part 8** procedure as modified by Part 56 and this practice direction.

And [Rule 56.1(1)(f)](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part56#56.1):

> (1) In this Section of this Part ‘**landlord and tenant claim** means a claim under –
>
> ...
>
> (f) section 214 of the Housing Act 2004.

- What is its purpose?

Shelter's [handy guide](https://england.shelter.org.uk/professional_resources/legal/court_action_and_complaints/court_process_and_hearings/process_and_rules_for_taking_a_case_to_court#title-6) offers this:

> The Part 8 procedure is used where a rule or practice direction requires or permits it [*see above*], or where the claimant seeks the court's decision on a question that is unlikely to involve a substantial dispute of fact.